# IndexError: list index out of range (Bloch sphere)

Tags: python-3.x, quantum-computing

I'm trying to build something called a Bloch Sphere, which is the 3-D representation of single quantum bit.  Currently, I'm creating a function that develops animation along the x-axis and here is the code that I've written.

```
def x_animation(self):
    #Y and Z are inputs from users
    Y1 = self.Y*(-1)
    Z1 = self.Z*(-1)
    #number of dots which consists animation
    length = 10
    for i in range(length+1):
        # an array of X,Y,Z coordinates of 10 dots
        xgate= []
        xgate_y = np.linspace(self.Y,Y1,length+1)
        xgate_z = np.linspace(self.Z,Z1,length+1)
        xgate.append([self.X,round(xgate_y[i],1),round(xgate_z[i],1)])
        plot(xgate[i][0],xgate[i][1],xgate[i][2])
```

However, I got the error below.

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-f56aa4b3a487> in <module>()
----> 1 q.x_animation()

<ipython-input-3-f74dcce093d4> in x_animation(self)
 57             xgate_z = np.linspace(self.Z,Z1,length+1)
 58           xgate.append([self.X,round(xgate_y[i],1),round(xgate_z[i],1)])
---> 59             plot(xgate[i][0],xgate[i][1],xgate[i][2])
 60 
 61     def x_gate(self):

IndexError: list index out of range
```

I would appreciate it if anyone help me with solving this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code initializes the list `xgate` to an empty list on each iteration, and then it appends one element to it, thus `xgate` never has more than one element in it by the time `plot` is called. But `plot` tries to access i-th element of `xgate`, which will succeed on the first iteration and fail on the second one (once `i=1`).

You should be able to fix this by moving list initialization `xgate = []` outside of the loop, so that it would actually accumulate the elements.

(I'm not sure initialization of `xgate_y` and `xgate_z` should be in the loop either, but those are not accumulated and should not cause this kind of an issue.)

Comment: Thank you so much for answering.  I put `plot` and `xgate=[]` outside of the loop and my program worked perfectly!

Comment: @MakotoNakai I'm glad this resolved your issue. Looks like you're new to SO (welcome!); you might want to check out https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235 for an explanation of accepting answers.